# File truncates after hitting a wide character

Tags: c++, wofstream

While trying to write some wide characters to a file, all output to the file stops after those characters.  I don't know what's going on.

```
wofstream file("c:\\test.txt");

file << L"seen" << L"您好" << "unseen";
```

Comment: This is only an example.  The real data is coming from the registry.

Comment: Show the real code that exhibits the behaviour.

Comment: Is "unseen" not being a wide literal intended?

Answer (score 1):

Non-ASCII characters in source code are parsed in an implementation defined way. Use either hex sequences or the newer (post-c99 or C++11) unicode character literals and use their UTF-8/16/32 codepoint representations.

This is implementation defined behavior, so unless you are absolutely sure you compiler does what you expect, don't do this.

Comment: My compiler and ide both allow this and do it properly

Comment: This is just an example.  The actual data is coming from the registry on a Chinese employee's workstation.

Comment: Bluebaron: http://codepad.org/m2bTCgxN. Do the characters fit in a 2-byte `wchar_t`? Windows doesn't support anything that does not fit in a 2-byte `wchar_t`, unfortunately...